# Apply border style to all pictures with VBA in MS Word 2010

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-word-2010

I have a large Word docx file with text and many pictures. I would like to apply a border/frame style to all pictures at once. I do not want to do that individually for all pictures.

So I believe a macro is the way to go, but am not very fluent in creating Word macros. I think this is the start, but get an error about trying to apply the settings to a `<hr>` element.

Here's the macro code I used. I suspect just a small tweak will fix it (allowing the code to run against all picture objects) is needed.

```
Sub addborder()
'
' addborder Macro
'
'
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            For j = 1 To .Borders.Count
                .Borders(j).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .Borders(j).Color = wdColorAutomatic
            Next j
        End With
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks.

---

**Added:**

Note that the document has some `<hr>` inside, and that element is stopping the macro (can't apply those parameters to the `<hr>` element). So the macro has to select only picture images.

Answer (score 2):

All of the pictures in your Word Document have to be formatted as 'In Line with Text' for that piece of code to work. Having the document text wrap around the image in any other way makes it a [VBA Shape Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221989(v=office.11).aspx) and not an InlineShape Object.

### [image: Picture Formats in Word]

Also, the Border**s** object includes all 4 sides. You shouldn't need your second For...Next statement to loop 4 four times to set the style and color on each side.

The last thing is that the border line was not easy to see on my pictures when I let it set to the default width size. You can also set the Linewidth property just to see if it's working.

In Office 2007, this works for me:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
                .Borders(1).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .Borders(1).Color = wdColorAutomatic
    ' optional  .Borders(1).LineWidth = wdLineWidth225pt

        End With
    Next i
End With
```

**EDIT:**

Concerning your `<hr>`  error. Not all InlineShape objects are pictures. You can specify in your VBA code to only select InlineShapes whose Type is Picture.

This is probably why I prefer to reference objects directly as 'InlineShape' instead of grouping them all together with 'InlineShape-s'. You can't easily get to the 'Type' property with InlineShape-s.

```
    Dim inshape As InlineShape
    Dim ashape As shape  

    For Each inshape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

      If inshape.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then

           inshape.Borders(1).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
           inshape.Borders(1).Color = wdColorAutomatic
 'optional inshape.Borders(1).LineWidth = wdLineWidth225pt

      End If
    Next

    'The second loop will look for pictures formatted as Shape objects

    For Each ashape In ActiveDocument.Shapes

       If ashape.Type = msoPicture Then

          ashape.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
          ashape.Line.Weight = 0.5 'default size is 0.5 pts'

       End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like Cathy's answer to this question, but I just want to add that you don't necessarily have to use the `Borders` member of `InlineShape` to get the surrounding lines, you can just use the `Line` member just like you do for a normal `Shape`, like so:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PicturesAll_Borders_Show()

    'for pictures which are "In Line with Text"
    Dim inShp As InlineShape
    For Each inShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If inShp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            With inShp.Line
                .Visible = True
                .Style = msoLineSingle
                .Weight = 1
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End With
        End If
    Next inShp

    'for pictures which are "With Text Wrapping"
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
            With shp.Line
                .Visible = True
                .Style = msoLineSingle
                .Weight = 1
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End With
        End If
    Next shp

End Sub
```

I also made a quick method to hide borders for all pictures in case someone finding this later needs it.

```
Sub PicturesAll_Borders_Hide()

    'for pictures which are "In Line with Text"
    Dim inShp As InlineShape
    For Each inShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If inShp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then inShp.Line.Visible = False
    Next inShp

    'for pictures which are "With Text Wrapping"
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoPicture Then shp.Line.Visible = False
    Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: I use the two scripts (with slight adaptations to my personal needs), and they work very well. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann glad to hear they helped! :)